# Integrating Jetty with Active Directory for authentication

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, jetty, authorization

I have been trying to intergrate an ordinary web-application to authenticate with Active Directory. I have followed the guide [Authentication with ldap](http://tmielke.blogspot.no/2011/12/securing-activemq-web-console-using.html), and the configuraiton doesn't seem to be very tricky.

After setup I am getting the following exception when I try to authenticate a user. There is not much help on Google, so I'll try my luck here to get some reflections from people.

`console.log:javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Error obtaining callback information. ----> User supplied credentials cannot be converted to char[] for    PasswordCallback: try using an ObjectCallback instead`

Comment: Hi @Moni have you got any hint on this problem. I am too facing the same

Comment: Hello @GnanamR, sorry for my very late answer. I struggled quite much myself with it, I even had to make changes to the code to find out the problem. Specifically, I tried to activate AD in ActiveMQ WebConsole web-app. I don't know whether your issue is caused by the same reason. Please see the solution.